# No desktop only blank screen

Tags: login, intel-graphics, configure

I started my Laptop this morning and after login there is only a black screen. I tried to re-install the desktop, but it didn't work.

When I rebooted the machine with Shift key pressed it displayed

```
configure drivers manually
```

I have an Intel graphics card in my HP G62 running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: have you done any changes/updates before shutting your laptop down last time?

Comment: I've had the same problem. The only thing that did it for me was clean install. What version you running? I ran into the problem when upgrading from 12.04 to 14,04 Did you update anything the last time it worked ?

Comment: Yupp one update was done for my printer's driver. So how can I clean that update using terminal?

Comment: yes 1 update was done

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS try

```
unity --replace
```

or, if you are running 12.04 LTS, try

```
unity --reset
```

Comment: @NickBailuc you have to reference the user or they won't get the message